# Express a method like a keyword

Tags: python

How can I express a method (e.g. `dir(os)`) like a keyword (e.g. `dir_ os`)? Is it even possible?

The opposite is quite easy to achieve:

```
# `assert` expressed like a method
def assert_(x): assert x
assert_(1 == 1)
```

Comment: You can't add custom keywords without modifying the language itself.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible.  Parentheses are required in order to call a function or method.

Comment: I think that is different between python versions.

Comment: @SelmanGenç Only for `print()` and `exec()` which have been converted to functions in Python 3.